# Learn Event Handling in Java

Tags: java, event-handling

I was looking forward to learn Event Handling in Java so, I googled Event Handling in Java and have followed through this link:
[WikiBook on Event Handling](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Event_Handling)

But it has a very simple example with no thread safety and other issues addressed. I want a complete understanding of the Event Handling model with **good and practical examples**. Can anyone suggest any good resource on it?

Comment: [Try this](http://www.javatpoint.com/event-handling-in-java)

Comment: @NeerajJain: Yeah, he directly jumps into the AWT framework. I need it from scratch.I mean, I could go on it later.

Comment: Then start with scratch , and then look for further big issues such as thread safety and other issues

Answer (score 0):

The Java Documentation is fine for event handling in Java :

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/
```

You can start from the most simple event handler for a button:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html
```

then move up to general principles for events and listeners:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html
```

then you have events for graphics such as swing :

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html
```

and for all type of events and how to handle them:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html
```

IBM documentation provides good coverage of thread issues when handling events:

```
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07265/
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Fair enough Hovercraft, but the question this guy is asking is so generic that I could either down vote it (which I don't like doing), either provide the source where a complete beginner could learn a lot from.

Comment: And that's why the question should (and will) be deleted. It has no place on this site as it is far off topic per the site rules. Otherwise if you want to post just links, post them in a comment as others have done.

Comment: Point taken, then delete it if you can, I don't have such powers in this site. And then delete the thousands of other questions that are replied providing links, and even getting tens or hundreds of up votes (because some people may actually find these to be useful) :)

Comment: Please read the meta article or re-read it before posting something foolish.